# Error parsing PCC subspace from PCCT ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I got this error after booting ubuntu:

> Error parsing PCC subspace from PCCT ubuntu

so i changed the OS and installed ubuntu again and I got the error again, I tried Fedora 27 and ubuntu 16.04 and none of them works because of the same problem but it works perfectly in live mode.

My system is Asus N56J.

Comment: Did you figure what was wrong? Weird no one has any good answers for this online.